# Regex string to search for multiple conditions

Tags: c#, regex, regex-lookarounds

I'm trying to write a Regex expression that'll match a complicated number of conditions. I'm trying to extract the number that follows after `ABC`, but there could be multiple places where `ABC 1234` appears in my string. I also have to account for when a number is used without `ABC`, but follows after it. Like, `ABC 1234 / 1134`, or `ABC 1234-1134`, or some thing else between the two numbers like `and`.

The strings I'm trying to match for look something like this:

```
ABC-210293CompletedReports  // Should match: ABC-210293
CC517036submittedbyfoobarforABC105799WRS877565 // Should match:  ABC105799
ABC#86765 // Should match: ABC#86765
abc99220 / 103743 // Should match: ABC99220 / 103743
AbC99220/103743 // Should match: ABC99220/103743
ABC 123 and 1123 // Should match: ABC 123 and 1123
SubmittedbyFooBar.forABC106156.Solutionbuilton4/23/20184:22PM // Should match: ABC106156
```

Right now, I this regex:

`((?i)ABC.(?-i))(\d[0-9]{0,10})|( *(\/|-|(?i)AND(?-i)) *\d[0-9]{0,10})`

will match each of the above strings besides the last one. It'll match `ABC106156`, but will also match the `/23` and `/20184` in the `4/23/20184:22PM` section. I don't know how to exclude `/` without loosing the matching expressions of `abc99220 / 103743` and `AbC99220/103743`.

I heard of look around, but I don't know how to go about it. How can I ignore the dates in this regex expression?

Comment: It is always possible to match and ignore something if you know the exact pattern of what you need to ignore. Add `\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{4}|` at the start, and only use captured substrings. Something like [this](https://regex101.com/r/mPZzUC/1).

Comment: Could you please explain the logic and expected results? I double I get it correctly (like all people below). Check out [this C# demo](https://ideone.com/KfncW3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an [alternation](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) to match what you do not want and capture in group what you do want.

The pattern which you don't want to capture is `4/23/20184:22PM` so you could match it with `\d\/\d+\/\d+:\d+[AP]M` or use a quantifier like `\d{2}` if you want to be more specific.

What you want to capture in a group could look like `(ABC ?[#-]?\d+|\b\d+\b)` which also uses an alternation for the pattern with `ABC` or only numbers surrounded by a word boundary `\b`.

[`(?i)(?:\d\/\d+\/\d+:\d+[AP]M|(ABC ?[#-]?\d+|\b\d+\b))`](https://regex101.com/r/VOSJj6/1)

[Demo C#](http://rextester.com/DVE38401)

Answer (score 1):

This RegEx does work for every given example. It's important that you make it case insensitive (`/gi`).

It searches for `ABC` then there can be an optional `-`,`#` or `whitespace` followed by `digits`(1 or more). After the digit(s) there can be an optional `"/"`, `" / "` or `" and "` followed by `digits`(1 or more).

```
/(ABC(?:-|#|\s)?\d+(?:\/| \/ | and )?\d+)/gi
```